# What is the significance of the Pendant of Memories?

Tags: the-legend-of-zelda, majoras-mask

In The Legend of Zelda: Majora's Mask, Kafei gives Link a "pendant of memories" to deliver to his fiancé, Anju, as a promise he will come to her. Upon receiving the pendant, Anju stammers "Ah! ...It's from Kafei! Th...th..thank you! Very much!" later saying that she is willing to wait.

I'm fairly certain no other significant information is given about this pendant in the game, but it's clear it has some sort of significant emotional history that Anju is aware of.

My question is, what might the significance of the pendant be? Examples of similar things from real-world cultures are satisfactory as a basis for the answer, as long as they fit into the events of the game fairly well.

Comment: https://zelda.gamepedia.com/Pendant_of_Memories

Comment: It appears to simply be a necklace with a pendant on it. It has no inherent value and no magical powers, etc. but is simply a keepsake of the relationship between Kafei and Anju, presumably a gift from one to the other.

Answer (score 3):

When Anju gives Link her letter to deliver to Kafei, she's worried that Kafei has skipped town to back out of their engagement. (She might even wonder whether he's still alive!) Kafei *does* want to go through with the wedding, but he can't show himself because the Skull Kid transformed him into a child and Sakon stole his Sun Mask. It's significant that Kafei gives the pendant in response to the letter—it means that Anju will understand it as  if he'd written an actual note in return.

For Anju, the Pendant of Memories says "I'm safe, I haven't abandoned you, and we're still gonna get married." It's a little bit similar to an engagement ring or a [promise ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-engagement_ring) in this way.

But I don't think the Pendant of Memories is supposed to have a *cultural* significance in the realm of Termina, or refer to a tradition in real-world culture. We see in Anju and Kafei's storyline that in Termina, married couples symbolize their bond by crafting masks—Kafei can't go back to Anju until he's recovered the Sun Mask he made that was stolen by Sakon. We can imagine a different game where Kafei can't see Anju for some other reason (i.e. still insecure about being four feet tall) and gives Link the Sun Mask to deliver: The message, for Anju, would be the same.

Without the culturally appropriate symbol of love with which to send this message, Kafei gives Link the Pendant of Memories—which in the Japanese version was called *Kāfei no Tarekazari,* Kafei's Pendant. He's been wearing the pendant all the time up to this point; it's a distinctive piece of jewelry that Link couldn't have gotten from anyone but Kafei.

It's a little bit like Kafei giving Anju his [dog tag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_tag) or [letterman's jacket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letterman_(sports)#Letter_jacket), but the token is far more unique than the latter and far more romantic than the former. When she receives it, she knows Kafei still loves her, and she knows he's serious.

Comment: All right...all that makes sense, but I had figured much (though not all) of that out already. More specifically I was wondering what the pendant itself may mean to them both in days past.